# How to determine which python modules were installed with `pip` and which with `apt`?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, python

I was trying to fix my problem with [ReText (installed system-wide with `pip3`)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075826/66509).
Two of my 16.04 LTS systems have different output of `pip3 list`.

I know that `pip3 list` shows all packages (installed with both `pip3` and `apt`/`apt-get`).

Also I know that

- APT installs stuff to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`;
- `pip3` installs system-wide stuff to `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`.

How to determine which python modules were installed with `pip` and which with `apt`?

Comment: Can't you just compare the two folders, like with `diff`?

Comment: @wjandrea I have already done such comparsion with Meld. I hope more standard, simple and programmatic way exists :)

Comment: Did you put together a script for obtaining the intended result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not cast in stone but from this [**Ask Ubuntu Q&A**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install):

> As @Radu Rădeanu pointed out in this answer, there would generally be
>   difference in names of packages as well. Canonical usually names
>   Python 2 packages as python- and Python 3 packages as
>   python3-. Whereas for pip we generally just need to use
>    for both Python 2 as well as Python3 packages.

Generally speaking then:

- If the package name starts with `python-` or `python3-` it was installed by `apt`.
- Otherwise the package was installed by `pip`

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same question.
A first, brute force, approach I though of is getting both lists, and programmatically get the difference.
In pseudocode:

```
pkg_all = $(pip3 list)
pkg_apt = $(dpkg -l | grep python3)
pkg_pip = substract(pkg_all, pkg_apt)
```

It shouldn't be hard to put together `subtract`.
Apply a given function to all elements of `pkg_all`, another function to all elements of `pkg_apt`, in such a way that both lists are brought to a common notation. Then sort both lists, and `diff`.

This simply adds to the accepted answer.

**Related**:

1. [How do I detect and remove Python packages installed via pip?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173323/how-do-i-detect-and-remove-python-packages-installed-via-pip)

Comment: Upvoting for novelty of idea without really thinking how to write a `subtract` command. Perhaps the `diff` command could be used somehow?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - Probably. See EDITed answer.